# PyQt4 application: buttons suddenly no longer works

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I was working some time ago (~8 months) on a PyQt4 application. Today I wanted to resume my work but for a strange reason some buttons which were fully working now does nothing when they're pressed. I checked the code and everything seems fine, so probably an update to Qt4 or PyQt4 messed the things up. I'm trying by some time to identify the issue, but no success until now. The UI is designed in QtDesigner and is loaded through `uic` module. The `clicked` signal is connected like this:

```
self.widget.signInButton.clicked.connect(self.do_signin)
```

where `self.widget` is an object returned by `uic.loadUi('ui/login.ui')`. I put a print in `do_signin` but it seems that the method isn't even called!

Maybe someone which knows more about the development of Qt/PyQT knows if something changed? The project is located at https://github.com/ov1d1u/cyuf (don't forget to also clone `libemussa` in `cyuf` directory), the main's window code is located in `cyuf.py` and the code which connects the signals with the buttons is located in `loginui.py`. Thank you.

Comment: Highly unlikely that a PyQt4 update broke your build, since there where only patch updates, which are source and binary forwards and backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what it was: I was using an old-style superclass initializer:

```
QObject.__init__(app)
```

changing with:

```
super(NameOfMyClass, self).__init__(app)
```

fixed the issue. Shame on me.